# SQL query doesnt return expected values

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables. 1st table stores coil information, 2nd table store coil information in transport and 3rd stores reserved coils.

- coils

| ID | SERIAL | COLOR | MATERIAL | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | 5 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 12346 | 4 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 12347 | 3 | 1 | 2 |

- coils_in_transport

| ID | SERIAL | COLOR | MATERIAL | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | f34S5 | 5 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | A23GG6 | 4 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | ff2S147 | 3 | 1 | 2 |

- reserved_coils

| ID | NUMBER | QUANTITY | START | END |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | 25 | 2022-05-01 | 2023-05-01 |
| 3 | 12347 | 252 | 2022-01-01 | 2023-05-01 |
| 4 | A23GG6 | 33 | 2022-04-01 | 2023-05-01 |
| 5 | ff2S147 | 35 | 2022-08-01 | 2023-05-01 |

I need to write query that will get all reserved coils (reserved_coils) that has status 2 and for each coil I need to join tables for materials and colors

material

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |

color

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |

I wrote query but it doesn't show coils in transport that are reserved, here is what I tried

```
SELECT a.QUANTITY, a.START, a.END, b.name, m.name 
FROM reserved_coils a 
LEFT JOIN coils b ON a.number = b.serial
LEFT JOIN coils_in_transport c ON a.number = c.serial
LEFT JOIN material m ON b.material = m.id
LEFT JOIN material b ON b.material = b.id
where b.status = 2 and c.status = 2
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Unless `coils` and `coils_transport`  have same serial, if `b.status`=`2`, `c.status` will be `null` and vice versa. Is it `b.status=2 and c.status=2` or `b.status=2 or c.status=2`?

Comment: provide more rows to your tables and add an expected output table that reflects the output of your shared input tables

Comment: Does this help? [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c49bf27f1978095d09532984596e65c4)

Answer (score 0):

To get all `coils` and `colis_in_transport` you need to use `UNION` for `SELECT` statements for both tables, each filtered by `status` value, which should be equal to `2`. Then you need to do a `JOIN` between `reserved_coils` and the result of `UNION` to filter out `reserved_coils` rows.

Your query would be like this

```
SELECT 
    r.quantity, 
    r.start, 
    r.[end], 
    c.serial, 
    material.name AS material, 
    color.name AS color
FROM reserved_coils r
JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM coils WHERE status = 2
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM coils_in_transport WHERE status = 2
) c ON r.number = c.serial
LEFT JOIN material ON material.id = c.material
LEFT JOIN color ON color.id = c.color
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=26b79981f7e7e5f33d89a271947665c8)

Answer (score 0):

If you want left join twice on same table, this might help

```sql
SELECT a.QUANTITY, a.START, a.[END], isnull(b.serial,c.serial) serial,isnull(c1.name,c2.name) color, isnull(m.name,n.name) material
FROM reserved_coils a 
LEFT JOIN coils b ON a.number = b.serial
LEFT JOIN coils_in_transport c ON a.number = c.serial
LEFT JOIN material m ON b.material = m.id
LEFT JOIN material n ON c.material = n.id
LEFT JOIN color c1 on b.color=c1.id
LEFT JOIN color c2 on c.color=c2.id
where isnull(b.status,c.status) = 2
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1ece41927ac8878df0547ff755ea8b7a)